# Android Collapsed Toolbar overflow menu has background

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm using a collapsing toolbar layout in an activity which should have to items always shown in the overflow menu. the issue is that as you can see below (on the top right corner) both items has a background of the collapsed toolbar instead of being on top of the cover image directly like the back arrow.

- All used drawables are vector drawables without background.

**Activity XML Layout:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ui.activities.WorkDetailsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
            app:collapsedTitleGravity="start"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/expandedToolbarTitle"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_cover_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="480dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_cover"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/down_dark_gradient" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_work" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/share_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_share_black"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<include layout="@layout/navigation_view" />
```

**Expanded Layout**

[image]

**Collapsed layout**

[image: CollapsedToolbar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the theme from toolbar 
`android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"` didn't  solve the issue, applying a theme that overrides the parent with a transparent background did. 
`<item name="android:background">@color/transparent</item>`